# Camera Intent not working in my code

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, imageview

I am trying to set the imageview with result data received from, camera and Gallery.

I have 4 ImageViews, so depending on the selected image views request code changes..and it is assigned to this capture and gallery variables.

```
private  void picselect(int capture, int gallery) {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel"};

    a=capture;
    b=gallery;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            EditProfile.this);
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        (cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg"));
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {

                    file.delete();
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                uricam = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                Log.d("shanOutput", String.valueOf(uricam));
                 takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uricam);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture,a);


            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {

                Intent photoPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(photoPic,b);


            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();

}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null,
            null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) { 

        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is my code written inside onActivityResult

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if(imageReturnedIntent!=null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    if(selectedImage!=null){

                        profileImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);}
                    sendImageToServer( String.valueOf(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage)),1);

                    Log.d("shanImage", String.valueOf(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage)));
                }


            }
```

Receiving picture from Gallery is working fine, but the part is returning null. what am I missing in my code. Can someone guide me to complete this module.

Comment: a=capture;
    b=gallery; there is required int value this one

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri` via the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`.

Since you are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you know where the image should be: at the location that you put into `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. So, look there for your image.

[This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates the use of `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. In particular, it uses `FileProvider`, as you cannot use `Uri.fromFile()` on Android 7.0+ devices once your `targetSdkVersion` rises to 24 or higher.

Comment: can you please suggest me what should I replace over there